# Simulating sedimenting cylinders with a particle system and molecular addon

Tags: python, particles

I want to simulate rod-like particles falling slowly down onto a surface. Eventually, my goal is to retrieve the thickness of the 'carpet' formed by those cylinders by this process.

For this, I have downloaded the molecular add_on, and set up a python script to run in the scripting window of blender

```
import bpy
import math


def cylinder_between(x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, r):

    dx = x2 - x1
    dy = y2 - y1
    dz = z2 - z1    
    dist = math.sqrt(dx**2 + dy**2 + dz**2)

    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cylinder_add(
        radius = r, 
        depth = dist,
        location = (dx/2 + x1, dy/2 + y1, dz/2 + z1)   ) 

    phi = math.atan2(dy, dx) 
    theta = math.acos(dz/dist) 

    bpy.context.object.rotation_euler[1] = theta 
    bpy.context.object.rotation_euler[2] = phi 
    bpy.context.object.name='dacyl'

cylinder_between(0,0,0,1,0,0,0.03)

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add(radius=8,location=(0,0,0))
bpy.context.object.name='bouncer'

bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='COLLISION')

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add(radius=5,location=(0,0,5))
emitter = bpy.context.object




bpy.ops.object.particle_system_add()    
psys1 = emitter.particle_systems[-1]
psys1.name = 'Drops'
pset1 = psys1.settings
pset1.name = 'DropSettings'
pset1.render_type = 'OBJECT'
pset1.dupli_object = bpy.data.objects["dacyl"]
pset1.particle_size=1
pset1.drag_factor=0.5
pset1.effector_weights.gravity=0.2
pset1.normal_factor =0
pset1.jitter_factor =0
pset1.frame_end=500
pset1.lifetime=10000
pset1.distribution = 'RAND'
pset1.use_rotations = True
pset1.phase_factor_random
pset1.rotation_mode = 'OB_Z'
pset1.rotation_factor_random = 1

pset1.mol_active = True
pset1.mol_density_active = True
pset1.mol_selfcollision_active = True
```

Where I have simply defined a cylinder to be the object of a particle system. I want the cylinders to avoid one another and this is why I have used the molecular add-on.

When I turn on the simulating engine of the molecular add-on, my cylinders fly all around the place but do not fall down anymore. Furthermore, they do not seem to intersect properly with the bottom plane which is set to 'collision', but rather only their centers seem to intersect the plane.
Lastly, I fail to see whether the cylinders really collide off of one another.

Could you explain to me what I am doing wrong ?
Regards, 
 any feedback appreciated

PS: I am aware the code looks a bit contrived and weird. I am starting with blender python and I took code snippets left and right from the stackexchange/google.